# WPF disable window auto resize

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I have

```
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
```

because I want to take advantage of WPF's auto resize. But when I hide some buttons the window width shrinks, this is expected behavior but I would like to disable that. Basically I want the window size to stay as it is after it is rendered. Is there a nice way to do that instead of calculating the width on start up and set it in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with code behind.

But you might want to set your buttons' `Visibility` to `Hidden` instead of `Collapse` to achive the desired behaviour.

Comment: The button has to be Collapsed because it will be ugly to have a big empty spot between buttons. Code behind calculating the width is just too ugly IMO so I rather not do that

Comment: @Steve you do not have to calculate the width, just pick the `ActualWidth`'s value, assign it to `Width` property and reset the `SizeToContent`, so the window would not resize again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size (fix size) of your window in its load event when the window got its width and height based on the size of its content.  You should can use something like this.Width = this.ActualWidth and this.Height= this.ActualHeight, in the load event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i do :
For Window Set:

```
 SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
 ContentRendered += DisableSizeToContent
```

Finally disable `SizeToContent` there:

```
private static void DisableSizeToContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Window win)
    {                
        win.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
    }
}
```

Still looking a solution for Async Bindings!